# Java Syntax for a list of comparable objects

Tags: java, list, comparable

I'm writing a method that takes as its only parameter a list of comparable objects and doesn't return anything. I am uncertain as to the syntax that it should have:

```
public static void methodName(List<Comparable<Object>> list) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

I think this is wrong because of the `<Object>` as a type for Comparable, which would mean the list can take an Integer and a Boolean as objects, but I don't want that. I want the list to take only one type, but that type has to implement the Comparable interface. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to take `Integer` and `Boolean` types when the method should work for all objects that implement `Comparable` anyway?

Comment: @Jake: It should work with a list of `Integer` and with a list of `Boolean`, but not with a list that contains both `Integer`s and `Boolean`s at the same time.

Comment: @Niklas Ah, got it, I misread the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe make it generic?

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void methodName(List<E> list) ...
```

Comment: Link to the Java tutorials for those who are curious [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)