# Java Questions Regarding declaring a list of Comparable objects

Tags: java

It is a pretty simple one. I want to declare a list of objects, but I want make sure all objects implemented the Comparable interface. What should I do? I try to write

```
   List<Comparable> heap = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
```

But compiler gives me a warning. What is the proper way to write it?

Thanks

Follow up:
I thought I had finished the question before I post it but apparently I didn't. So let me finish it up.

My purpose is to have a list of objects that:

1. Implements the Comparable  interface
2. Are all with the same type

Can I make it

```
   List<Comparable<?>> heap = new ArrayList<Comparable<?>>()
```

No, I can't. The reason is because I need to retrieve the elements from the list and compare them. like:

```
   if( heap.get(0).compareTo(heap.get(1)) > 0)
```

If I use wildcard `List<Comparable<?>>`, the complier will give me an error. Saying heap.get(0) cannot match heap.get(1) So I need to know the correct way to declare it.

I find somebody asking me what the warning is.... that surprises me.....well, the warning is:
Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable should be parameterized

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Syntax for a list of comparable objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763390/java-syntax-for-a-list-of-comparable-objects)

Comment: I think, as @arshajii pointed out, it's because Comparable is not typed that the warning is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your objects are of the same type (let's say f.e. `FooType`), then just use a `List<FooType>`.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using the raw type `Comparable`. You can try giving `Comparable` a [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) type parameter:

```
List<Comparable<?>> heap = new ArrayList<Comparable<?>>();
```

---

If you want the objects to all be of the same type, you can do something along the lines of

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> getList() {
    ...
}
```

and return your list from `getList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write a method that only takes a type that extends Comparable and returns a List of that type:

```
public <T extends Comparable> List<T> getComparableList(T t) {
    List<T> heap = new ArrayList<T>();
    return heap;
}
```